# PHPで発生したエラーをInternal Server Errorとして、IISに渡したい

Tags: php, iis

現在PHPのアプリを作成しています
ほぼ完成し、リリースに向けて調整中なのですが
PHPで発生したスクリプトエラーをIISのInternal Server Errorとして引き渡すことは出来ないでしょうか

```
<?php
    aa
try{
....
}catch(Exception $ex){
....
}

?>
```

としたときに、画面上に

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AAAAA\BBBBB.php on line 3
```

と表示されます(例として極端すぎるかもしれませんが)

これを、この様なPHPのエラーでは無く
IISで表示する一般的なエラー画面を表示したいと思っています

PHPのログは

```
[25-Aug-2015 11:51:25 Asia/Tokyo] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AAAAA\BBBB.php on line 3
```

IISのログは

```
2015-08-25 02:48:43 POST /AAAAA/BBBBB.php - - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:40.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/40.0 http://localhost/AAAAA/ 200 0 343
```

となっており、どうもIIS側は正常終了になってしまっているようです

出来ればIISにもエラーとして通知したいのですがphp.iniの設定などはどこをいじればいいのでしょう

Comment: そのIISのログの`0`と`343`では?

Answer (score 3):

もしHTTP`200`をHTTP`500`に替えたかったら、[`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/ja/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)が`Off`または`0`にしよう。

`display_errors=On`または`display_errors=1`であれば、たとえ[`E_PARSE`](http://php.net/manual/ja/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-parse)や`E_ERROR` でも、PHPエンジンはHTTP`200`を出力する。

---

もしIISのログにPHPのエラーが見えるようになりたかったら、`error_log`を使おう。例えば`php.ini`こうすると：

```
error_log=syslog
log_errors=1
error_reporting=-1;全部
log_errors_max_len=0;『無限』
```

エラーがシステムロガー（[`syslog`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.syslog.php)と同じ目的地）に渡す:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[参考](http://php.net/manual/ja/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)によると、`error_log`設定しなければ、ログは自動的にIISのとこへ行く:

> このディレクティブが設定されていない場合、エラーは SAPI エラーロガーに送信されます。これは、例えば Apache のエラーログ、 あるいは CLI なら stderr になります。

そう書いてあるけど、なんだかどうしてもダメになるしかない。（エラーメッセージがIISのログに表示されず、ブラウザで見える。多分[web.config](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx)どこか間違ったんのせいだ（[英語のリンク](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1808680/632951)）。）

「`error_log`設定しない場合」について指示実行しなかったら、直接に設定すればいい。まずサイトログの場所を見つけ:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

、`php.ini`を設定する。例:

```
error_log="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_in150828.log"
```

（注意、一つのサーバーには複数のサイトを持つことでもある 。各サイトには独自のログがある。）

次、`iisreset`で再起動する、または:

```
net stop w3svc
net start w3svc
```

最後に**書き込みと読み込み**の許可、選択したユーザーに与える:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そのユーザーはほとんど`IIS_IUSRS`です。（`IUSR`って主張する意見を聞いたことがあるけど、それでしてみた結果は成し遂げられない。でもそちらの場合が成し遂げられるかもしれない。）「[認証](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx)」使えば、認証されたユーザー（[英語のリンク](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17765116/632951)）です。

Comment: 「PHPでエラーが起きた時にIIS標準のエラーページを表示したい。レスポンスコードが500ではなく200になっているのが原因かもしれない。」という質問だと思うのですが、このこととログの出力先は関係あるのでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist , なるほど。`200`の原因は`display_errors=1`（または`On`). もし`display_errors=0`/`display_errors=Off`でしたら、`200`が`500`になる。

Answer (score 1):

Syntaxエラーでも対応できる方法というのは知らないですが、PHPに用意された機能を組み合わせるとある程度のエラーハンドリングはできるようになります。
要素としては、
`header()`
`register_shutdown_function()`
`error_get_last()`
`ob_start()`
と言ったものを使います。
つまり、スクリプトが終了したときになぜ自分が止まったのかerror_get_last()で調べて、正常終了でなければheader()でエラーステータスを設定するようにします。その際、header()はそれまでにデータが送信されていてはいけないという制約があるので、最初にob_start()でバッファリングしてメッセージの送信は保留させます。
かなり大掛かりな機構になるので、最終調整でちょちょっと入れるというわけにはいかないですが。私はJSONでデータを送るクラスにこれを仕込んでいました。主にデバッグするのにエラーログを見るのが面倒だから、ですが。

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error は HTTP コード500番台ですので
PHPのなかで500系のレスポンスを返せば良い気がします。

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```